# Difference between "sometime" and "sometimes"

Tags: differences, suffixes

I see some people use *sometime* and some people use *sometimes*. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Well, **sometimes** is used when you speak about an activity that is repeated. For example:

*I go to the church sometimes.*

You don't go there every time but only **sometimes**.

On the other hand **sometime** is used when you speak about a singular activity, in the future and indefinite time.

*I'll get around to finishing that project sometime.*

You will probably do it but yet don't know when.
If I'm mistaken, someone please correct me.

Comment: Correct.  "Sometime" also has a parallel adjectival use:  if you go to church sometimes, you're a *sometime* churchgoer.

Comment: wonderful thanks. How about Friday and Fridays? what is the different between these?

Comment: I will visit my grandmother on Friday. (I will do it this particular Friday)
I visit my grandmother on Fridays. (I go there every Friday)

Answer (score 1):

Sometime and Sometimes. One is singular. One is Plural.

Comment: I go to the church sometimes.

Comment: I'll get around to finishing that project sometime.